# Pandas: filling null values based on values in multiple other columns

Tags: python, pandas, null

I have this in a Pandas DataFrame:

```
    site    channel week    value   
0   Canada  A       W01     NaN     
1   Canada  A       W02     NaN    
2   Canada  A       W03     12     
3   Canada  B       W01     NaN   
4   Canada  B       W02     NaN     
5   Canada  B       W03     66
```

I need to get this:

```
    site    channel week    value   
0   Canada  A       W01     12      
1   Canada  A       W02     12    
2   Canada  A       W03     12     
3   Canada  B       W01     66   
4   Canada  B       W02     66      
5   Canada  B       W03     66
```

In words, I need to fill the null values in column `value` with the values that correspond to the **specific combination** of `site` and `channel`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `df.groupby(['site', 'channel']).bfill()`, might want to use `df.groupby(['site', 'channel']).bfill().ffill()` just to be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) if always last non numeric values per groups and all another values are `NaN`s:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['site', 'channel']).bfill()
```

Better general solution if possible some only `NaN`s groups:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['site', 'channel']).apply(lambda x: x.bfill.ffill())
```

Comment: groupby! I was having a hard time getting the distinct combinations of site and channel and this nails it. Thanks @jezrael!